# JQueryUI dialog, get information about what button user pushed to codebehind. ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

How to do this? We've tried setting the value on hiddenfield and trying to get that value in codebehind without success. We are able to set the value to a  but then we can't get the value to codebehind.

This is the JqueryUI dialog. When a user push the nej button(no) nothing should happen. But when user push the Ja(yes) button we want a codebehind method to run.

```
function RemProfile(message, title) {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog2").html(message);
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            title: title,
            buttons: {
                Ja: function () {
                    document.getElementById("lblremove").innerHTML = "true";
                    $("#hdnResultValue").val("true");
                    window.location = 'Profile.aspx';
                },
                Nej: function () {
                    document.getElementById("lblremove").innerHTML = "false";
                    $("#hdnResultValue").val("false");
                    window.location = 'Profile.aspx';
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    });
};
```

The button:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updateremoveprofile">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResultValue" Value="" runat="server" />

        <label id="lblremove"> hej</label>
        <asp:Button ID="RemoveProfile" runat="server" Text="Ta bort din profil" OnClick="RemoveProfile_Click" OnClientClick="RemProfile();" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void RemoveProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "Vill du ta bort din profil?";
    string title = " Borttagning";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updateremoveprofile, updateremoveprofile.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "RemProfile('" + message + "','" + title + "');", true);
    var h = hdnResultValue.Value;
}
```

Dialog div:

```
<div id="dialog2" style="display: none">

</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend calling web methods from dialog buttons instead

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the ClientID of the hidden field when asssigning the value?

```
$("#<%= hdnResultValue.ClientID %>").val("");
```

or add to the hiddenfield the property [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so the id remains the same after render

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResultValue" Value="" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your yes/no functions appear to be setting the window.location. This would cause the page to change, thereby stopping any running javascript. You probably want to make an ajax call, or make the form submit to cause a postback.

`$('#formname').submit()` should cause the form to post back to the server.